# EaselJS Performance. Scaling an image, should I cache it?

Tags: performance, canvas, createjs, easeljs

In EaselJS, in a game I am currently making I find the images look much crisper if I import them at twice the intended size and then at runtime I scale them to 50% their size.

Ie.
myimage.scaleX = myimage.scaleY = 0.5;

Doing this does seem to affect performance.  I find the game runs slower.  I understand there are 4 times as many pixels in memory for each image.

Would caching the scaled image help?  That would create another canvas in memory which sounds scary if I have 50 images in my game (that would make 50 canvas' in memory.

Not sure how other people solve this problem.

Thanks for any advice you can give!

Ryan

Answer (score 1):

Here some points to help you:

Make image cache does not improve performance.
The cache create an image of the DisplayObject, then only has improved performance for a group of images or fonts, shape which has a large cost in the visual part.

should not have visual gain of redirecting with image if 1: 1.
Some parent had to have scale diferent than 1;

bye,